# How to decode JPG/PNG in python?

Tags: python, image

This is a code of a JPG/PNG(I don't know exactly)
[Here's on google docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MGra5kq7pIoZQQCC2KqVkdVLu6RuPm-fCcg8CQHQi0U/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to decode it in Python to complete image and show it using Pillow or something like that. Do you know any libraries or ways how to decode it? Thanks!

Comment: Please add some more information and what you've already tried.

Comment: It's a JPEG image. (By exclusion -- it is not a PNG image, as can be seen by its header.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## (for Python 3)

If the image is stored as a binary file, open it directly:

```
import PIL

# Create Image object
picture = PIL.Image.open('picture_code.dat')

#display image
picture.show()

# print whether JPEG, PNG, etc.
print(picture.format)
```

If the image is stored as hex in a plaintext file `picture_code.dat` similar to your Google Docs link, it needs to first be converted to binary data:

```
import binascii
import PIL
import io

# Open plaintext file with hex
picture_hex = open('picture_code.dat').read()

# Convert hex to binary data
picture_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(picture_hex)

# Convert bytes to stream (file-like object in memory)
picture_stream = io.BytesIO(picture_bytes)

# Create Image object
picture = PIL.Image.open(picture_stream)

#display image
picture.show()

# print whether JPEG, PNG, etc.
print(picture.format)
```